# Клонирование приватного репозитория (в пароле есть спец-символы)

Tags: git, url, urlencode

Как заклонить приватную репку?

```
git clone https://user:difficult/password@git.domain.ru/db
```

При этом, у меня в пароле есть /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следует использовать %-кодировку. Например можно воспользоваться [этим](https://www.urldecoder.org/) сервисом.

Comment: я с паролями вообще не парюсь. **SSH** ключ взял, и всё...

Comment: ага, пароли пароли должны знать все в этих ваших интернетах. а [локально заменять символы](https://stackoverflow.com/q/296536/4827341) ни в коем случае нельзя. но это не точно.